# Angular 5 and chart.js ts error

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

In Angular 5 I installed chartjs and its types like this:

yarn add  chart.js --save

yarn add @types/chartjs --dev

i have chart like this everything looks good but in terminal i have the following error .. how can i fix this issue,, thanks :

my chart this code is in ngAfterinit:

```
import * as Chart from 'chart.js';


new Chart(<HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("user-rev-chart"), {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ["5 star", "4 start", "3 start", "2 star", "1 star"],
    datasets: [
      {
        fill: true,
        label: false,
        backgroundColor: ["#a1a7b3", "#a1a7b3", "#a1a7b3", "#a1a7b3", "#a1a7b3"],
        data: [10, 2, 5, 4, 5]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: false,
    legend: {display: false},
    title: {
      display: false,
      text: ''
    },
    scales:
      {
        yAxes: [{
          // barPercentage: 0.4,
          barThickness: 20,
          barPercentage: .5,
          categoryPercentage: .2,
          isFixedWidth: true,
          //Number - Pixel width of the bar
          barWidth: 20,
          gridLines: {
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            min: 0,
            stepSize: 1,
            fixedStepSize: 1,
          }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          display: false,
          gridLines: {
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            min: 0,
            stepSize: 1,
            fixedStepSize: 1,
          }
        }],
      }
  }
});
```

ERROR:

```
 ERROR in src/app/components/home/detail/detail.component.ts(253,77): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ type: string; data: { labels: string[]; datasets: { fill: true; label: boolean; backgroundColor...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChartConfiguration'.
  Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
    Type '{ labels: string[]; datasets: { fill: true; label: boolean; backgroundColor: string[]; data: numb...' is not assignable to type 'ChartData'.
      Types of property 'datasets' are incompatible.
        Type '{ fill: true; label: boolean; backgroundColor: string[]; data: number[]; }[]' is not assignable to type 'ChartDataSets[]'.
          Type '{ fill: true; label: boolean; backgroundColor: string[]; data: number[]; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartDataSets'.
            Types of property 'label' are incompatible.
              Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Comment: Check what you are getting when you print 
      document.getElementById("user-rev-chart")

Comment: i get `canvas id="user-rev-chart" _ngcontent-c8="" dir="rtl" height="200" width="300" ng-reflect-dir="rtl">`

Comment: I recently had this issue... although my chart configuration was declared outside the the       `new Chart()...`        declaration. What I did was to add a type like so                 
 `let data: ChartConfiguration = { type: 'horizontalBar....}`        this way I was able to see the attributes that was causing the type errors... hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Try [angular2-chartjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-chartjs) which is very useful angular library for chartjs

```
npm install angular2-chartjs chart.js --save
npm install @types/chart.js --save
```

Import and declare **ChartModule** in app.module.ts

```
...
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-chartjs';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [...,  ChartModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

In **AppComponent.ts** declare chart **chart, type, data, options** properties and assign values in ngOnInit method

```
...
@ViewChild(ChartComponent) chart: ChartComponent;
type;
data;
options;
...

ngOnInit() {

    this.type = 'horizontalBar';
    this.data = {
        labels: ["5 star", "4 start", "3 start", "2 star", "1 star"],
        datasets: [
            {
                fill: true,
                label: false,
                backgroundColor: ["#a1a7b3", "#a1a7b3", "#a1a7b3", "#a1a7b3", "#a1a7b3"],
                data: [10, 2, 5, 4, 5]
            }
        ]
    }
    this.options = {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: false,
        legend: { display: false },
        title: {
            display: false,
            text: ''
        },
        scales:
            {
                yAxes: [{
                    // barPercentage: 0.4,
                    barThickness: 20,
                    barPercentage: .5,
                    categoryPercentage: .2,
                    isFixedWidth: true,
                    //Number - Pixel width of the bar
                    barWidth: 20,
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                        stepSize: 1,
                        fixedStepSize: 1,
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    display: false,
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                        stepSize: 1,
                        fixedStepSize: 1,
                    }
                }],
            }
    }
}
```

In **AppComponent.html** template include **chart** tag

```
...
<chart #chart [type]="type" [data]="data" [options]="options" style="height: 100%"></chart>
```

Preview link for implementation of your horizontal bar https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-geq984